# What material can wick up fluids while not allowing micro-organisms to pass?

Tags: materials, fluid, biomedical-engineering, fluid-filtration, porous-medium

I'm looking for a material that can wick up a solution containing nutrients and sugars. The dirty side of the wick should touch a medium to draw up the solution, on the clean side of the wick sterility should be maintained. Do you know of any material that will allow wicking of the fluid while stopping micro-organisms? Antibacterial properties of the material are a plus.

Comment: interesting question. there must be something like this. "wicking" implies no pumping pressure for the nutrient mix... polymer membranes perhaps? (but i believe they tend to be hydrophobic, maybe not always). Or a packed bed in a tube (granularity and surface properties can be fine tuned, a-la chromatography components) with a filter for the bigger things on the dirty side?

Comment: I'm currently thinking about using cellulose. I've seen some companies making filter paper with a 0.22um pore size made from cellulose and from using them they seem to wet quite well.